# Does anyone know why I get this message when looking into Local Storage from my vue compnent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Anyone know how I can see my local storage data from user information. I keep geeting this message when i look in the web developer local storage section.  I see this message

> loglevel:webpack-dev-server:"SILENT"

I'm trying to display what the input and data that the user placed in into local storage. After I will create a connection to a MongoDB server. But I need to see data being saved and stored and then later validated.

Here is my code from my Signup.vue that handles the infromation

```
  <template>
    <div id="register">
        <form>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" v-model="form.firstName"/>

            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" @v-model="form.lastName"/>

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" v-model="form.email"/>

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" v-model="form.password"/>

            <button type="submit">Register!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            form: {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                email: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        //methid take two parameters input or local parameter and the value of it 'firstname'-john
        updateForm (input, value){
            this.form[input] = value

            let storedForm = this.openStorage() //extract openstorage and place in storedform
                if(!storedForm) storedForm = {} //if no data, then make empty object

            storedForm[input] = value //store new value
                this.saveStorage(storedForm) //save changes in saveStorage function which is connected to local storage
        },
        mounted() {
            if (localStorage.name){
                this.name = localStorage.name;
            }
        },
        //opening local storage form
        openStorage(){
            return JSON.pasrse(localStorage.getItem('form'))
        },
        //saving local storage data
        saveStorage(){
            localStorage.setItem('form', JSON.stringify(form))
        }
        
    },
    watch: {
        name(newName){
            localStorage.name = newName;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

`loglevel:webpack-dev-server:"SILENT"` in localstorage is just a variable used by Webpack dev server. It has nothing to do with your code. You code does not work.

Please clean up your code, and make sure everything else works. I see multiple problems.

`this.name` is not defined

Add an event handler to `<form @submit.prevent="">`

remove `@` from `@v-model="form.lastName"`

`localStorage.name` is not a function. Maybe you are looking for `localStorage.getItem('name')`

`updateForm` never gets called

You cannot access an object using index `storedForm[input]`

`mounted` is not a method you should implement yourself

Take a look at [this simple working example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) to get started